# How to mass delete one line from all posts

Tags: bulk, customization

I need to delete some content from all posts.

Every post starts with this line:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/picture.jpg" alt="" /></p>
```

So I want to delete this line from all posts from my database at once.

I know I can edit it in phpmyadmin but I do not know how to do it.

Here is how every post looks:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/picture.jpg" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">here is some text.</p>
```

So basically I want to mass remove this very line:

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/picture.jpg" alt="" /></p>
```

from every post on the site.

Postscriptum, I am completely newbie.

Comment: More of a MySQL question. If you want to do this from PHPMyAdmin then you could try something like this: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE( post_content, 'from', 'to' ) WHERE post_type = 'post' AND ID = 123;`. Where you adjust the *from* and *to* values, the ID and post type and the `wp_posts` table name. You can then remove the `ID` and `post_type` restrictions after testing. But remember to BACKUP up your db before!

Comment: Ok but can you describe how I should do it step by step?

Comment: Go to PHPmyadmin -> Click on the required database -> Export your DB -> Run the query given by birgire. If the test works, go ahead altering the query for your requirement.

Comment: I have exported the database, now I am on localhost »Database: sitename »Table: wp_posts and there are many files so I do not know which choose?

Comment: So should I add this in Run SQL query/queries on database sitename? What exactly should I put there? 
I am bit confused by this post, like I said I am completely newbie.

Answer (score 2):

To use phpMyAdmin follow the steps below:

```
Login to phpMyAdmin panel and select your WordPress database.
Click on the SQL tab which will bring you to a page with a SQL query box.
```

Once you see the SQL query box, like the image shown below, you can run your SQL query there.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/picture.jpg" alt="" /></p>', '');
```

[image: phpmyadmin SQL Query box]

Answer (score 0):

Good advice. It worked for me, but I had to put quotes around the table and field name.

```
UPDATE `wp_edeals_posts` SET `post_content`= REPLACE(post_content, '<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/picture.jpg" alt="" /></p>', '')
```